# what's the better call a function with all needed code inside, or a function with an other function inside with the needed code?

Tags: java, javascript, php, c++

I don't know how to formulate the question more accurately(because i'm not so good in English) but let me explain with some example (I work mostly on php ,javascript and java):

which style is better or more efficient?

```
function foo(){
    //somecode1
    requiredByFoo();
}
function requiredByFoo(){
    //somecode2
}
```

or

```
function foo(){
   //someCode1
   //somecode2
}
```

I ask this because i'm learning to program and I want to have good habits and do efficient code. Thanks ! :D

Comment: Each function should only do one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what the actual code is but in general, as people are saying, more methods is mostly a good things. Each method should do one thing and it keeps the code blocks much smaller.

- **Testing** is much easier if the methods are small and many since you can test each method separately and if it is not doing many things the number of possible outcomes/flows are easier to grasp.
- The code is much **easier** to **understand** when written in this way, it mitigates the need to read row after row of code to understand what each method does, if it does what it is named and it is small, then that is usually enough.
- If the code is made into smaller parts it is much easier to **reuse** different parts of the code which in turns **reduces code duplication** as well.

There are probably a lot of other pros that I am not thinking about right now. If you want more information you should look up **SRP** (Single Responsibility Principle) and other **lean and agile practices** that are good know.

Answer (score 0):

Each function should do only one thing based on your design. If SomeCode 1 and SomeCode 2 are two pieces doing a function together, take the later approach.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of procedural language, It is always good to write a function that would deliver one specific task so that further you can reuse this. So always keep your function code is as small as possible and call one function from another.

Answer (score 0):

In term of memory use, both codes will consume the same memory, as the classes containing the function code will be loaded in memory once, no matter how much times you call the functions.
In terms of design, your code should be as extensible as possible, hence you should fragment your business logic in as much classes and functions as possible.

As explained before this doesn't cause more memory consumption in Java.

Comment: No clue who did that but I'll put you back to 0 at least since I see no reason why someone would down your answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: Not my down vote, but perhaps because: 1) you have no idea about memory use, that is entirely implementation dependent. 2) There are no classes in ECMAScript. 3) "fragment your business logic in as much classes and functions as possible" does not sound like a good strategy. 4) JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: All I said is right for Java